# Are holomorphic vector bundles over Kähler manifolds Kähler

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, complex-geometry

Let $X$ be a Kähler manifold and $E\to X$ a holomorphic vector bundle. Is there a Kähler structure on $E$ compatible with its complex structure?

Comment: I recall that the result is true, and the proof uses: (1) pulling back the Kaehler form from the base and then (2) adding $\partial\bar\partial u$ for a suitable function $u$. Locally, such a function $u$ exists, obviously. Globally, you will need to use a partition of unity. But I can't remember how you ensure that the form remains positive globally.

Comment: @BenMcKay: when you glue locally defined Riemannian metrics via a partition of unity the resulting tensor is positive definite because being positive definite is a convex property and so it's preserved by convex linear combinations. Can the same thing be used here here, or I misunderstood the construction?

Comment: If $\pi:E\to X$ is the projection, then $\pi^*E$ is a vector bundle on $E$ that can be identified with the vertical distribution $T_{\pi}\subseteq T_E$ for $\pi$. Then I think $T_E = T_{\pi}\oplus \pi^* T_X$. A Hermitian metric $h$ on $E$ induces a Hermitian form $h_\pi$ and a metric $g_{\pi}$  on $T_{\pi}$. Let $g$ be the Kaehler metric on $X$, which can be pulled back to $g_H$ on $\pi^* T_X$. Is the resulting tensor $g_{E}:=g_{\pi}\oplus g_H$ Kaehler?

Comment: @Qfwfq: The difficulty is the Kaehler condition. Partitions of unity gluing together a Riemannian or Hermitian metric will not ensure Kaehlerity, because that involves first derivatives of the functions in the partition of unity.

Comment: You can take euclidean norm $|| \cdot ||^2$ as fibervise Kahler potential; then $\epsilon \partial \bar \partial ||v||^2 + \pi^* \omega$ is Kahler form for small $\epsilon$ — derivatives of unity partition are irrelevant because you can take $\epsilon$ arbitrarily small and positivity is open condition. For affine bundles situation is analogous, but they may fail to be Stein.

Comment: @DenisT. It seems to me that, in order to know that one $\epsilon$ will work for all of $X$, you need some compactness argument. I feel that this could be avoided by being more clever, but it wasn't comletely obvious to me. Am I missing something?

Comment: You are right, I was assuming that base is compact. (If base is noncompact, but bundle admits connection of bounded curvature, it still works, but otherwise, of course, not).

Answer (score 6):

Proposition 3.18 of Voisin's *Hodge Theory and Complex Algebraic Geometry I* says that, if $X$ is compact Kahler and $E$ is a holomorphic vector bundle over $X$, then $\mathbb{P}(E)$ is Kahler. Since $E$ embeds as an open submanifold of $\mathbb{P}(E \oplus \mathbb{C})$, this establishes your result for $X$ compact, and I think her proof could be simplified if you just want the vector bundle version and not the projective bundle version. But it looks to me like she actually is using compactness in a nontrivial way.

Comment: Perhaps "the vector bundle version"?

Comment: Fixed, thanks! (Unless you meant something more significant than the typo "tthe" for "the".)